# Error messages from TensorContract and TensorReduce

Tags: warning-messages, tensors

I am struggling with a few errors when using symbolic tensors.
I am using mathematica 9.0.1.0, linux x86.

The following code generates what seems to me an incorrect tensor, this is the smallest example I could find:

```
$Assumptions = {V ∈ Vectors[3, Reals]};

tp = TensorProduct;

TensorContract[
  V~tp~TensorContract[V~tp~V~tp~V~tp~V~tp~V~tp~V, {{1, 3}, {2, 6}}]~tp~V, 
  {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
] // TensorExpand
```

This generates the error:

> TensorContract::lvreps: Contractions {{2,4},{3,7},{1,4},{6,8}} contain repeated levels.

Where I think the result should have been:

```
TensorContract[
  V~tp~V~tp~V~tp~V~tp~V~tp~V~tp~V~tp~V,
  {{2, 4}, {3,7}, {1, 5}, {6, 8}}
]
```

Next it what seems like a bug:

```
$Assumptions =  {
  R ∈ Matrices[{3, 3}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]], 
  F ∈ Matrices[{3, 3}], 
  Inverse[R] ∈ Matrices[{3, 3}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]], 
  Inverse[F] ∈ Matrices[{3, 3}]
};

F.Inverse[R.F] // TensorReduce
```

The message generated was

> Mathematica has detected an internal error: vMessage ENULL

The answer should have been

```
Inverse[R]
```

I emailed support and they answered that this error is not generated on a windows machine in Mathematica 10. I thought I might just log it here.

These two errors together have made it impossible for me to use symbolic tensors. If any one can please suggest workarounds, or comment if these same errors where generated in version 10 on a Linux computer.

Related post on using [symbolic inverse](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20263/tensorcontract-of-inverse-matrix), though it is not a complete fix as it generates `IdentityMatrix[n]` which is incompatible with symbolic tensor manipulation.

Comment: I think you should mail support again concerning the first error -- I'm seeing the same on 10.0.1 on both OS X and the cloud. It looks a bug to me. As for the inverse error message, I don't see it after I clean up your $Assumptions code (there were some improperly pasted characters that I removed); it just gives me `F.MatrixPower[R.F, -1]`.

Comment: Yes now I will email support. I also still get the error for the inverse matrix, but perhaps it is restricted to version 9. Thanks for the clean up.

Comment: After upgrading to Mathematica 10.1 the above bugs and errors have been solved. Only detail being that `F.MatrixPower[R.F, -1]` does not simplify to `MatrixPower[R,-1]` as it should (with the correct assumptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see no clear pattern to the errors caused by `TensorExpand`, we can not pick out the special cases that case this error and just avoid them. So instead I choose to implement my own function `TensorReduceContract` to reduce tensor contractions. It is used like this:

```
tp = TensorProduct;

$Assumptions = {m  ∈ Arrays[ {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, Reals], n  ∈ Arrays[ {3, 3}, Reals], p  ∈ Arrays[ {3, 3}, Reals]};

TensorContract[n~tp~TensorContract[m, {{2, 4}, {3, 5}, {6, 8}}]~tp~p,{{2, 5}, {4, 6}}] // TensorReduceContract

>Out = TensorContract[ n~tp~m~tp~p, {{2, 11}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}, {8,10}, {9, 12}}]
```

Rather than

```
TensorContract[n~tp~TensorContract[m, list2]~tp~p, list1] // TensorExpand

> Out = TensorContract::lvreps: Contractions {{4,6},{5,7},{8,10},{2,11},{6,12}} contain repeated levels. 

> Out= TensorContract[ n~tp~m~tp~p, {{4, 6}, {5, 7}, {8, 10}, {2,11}, {6, 12}}]
```

Tensor contraction is [defined here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction). Here is how to code `TensorReduceContract`:

```
TensorReduceContract[tensor_] := tensor //. subTensorReduceContract

subTensorReduceContract = {
TensorContract[
 n_~tp~TensorContract[m_, list1_]~tp~p_,list2_] :> TensorContract[n~tp~m~tp~p,
  Sort[Join[ 
   list1 + TensorRank[n],
   Map[
    Complement[ 
       Range[TensorRank[n~tp~m~tp~p]], 
       Flatten[list1 + TensorRank[n]] ][[#]] &, list2]
   ]]
  ] 
};
```

Finally, the quality check below shows that `TensorExpand` almost never differs (after millions of trials) from `TensorReduceContract`. Here is a randomized check:

```
setRandomContraction[rank_]:=
(
setContract= RandomChoice[Range[rank], RandomChoice[Range[rank]] ]//Intersection; 
setContract=Drop[setContract, Length[setContract]~Mod~2];
If[Length[setContract]>1,ArrayReshape[setContract,  {Length[setContract]/2,2}],setContract ]
);

tensorRanks =ConstantArray[3,#]&/@Range[20];

Do[ $Assumptions=(# ∈ Arrays[ RandomChoice[tensorRanks],Reals])&/@{n,m,p};

    setContractm = setRandomContraction[ TensorRank[m]];
    setContract = setRandomContraction[ TensorRank[n~tp~m~tp~p] - 2 Length[setContractm]];

   If[ ( TensorExpand[#] =!= TensorReduceContract[#]) & @ TensorContract[n~tp~TensorContract[m, setContractm]~tp~p, setContract]
   ,  
     Print["Tensor Expand Differs: ", TensorContract[n~tp~TensorContract[m, setContractm]~tp~p, setContract] ];
  ];
, {1000000}]
```

The main cases that these two `TensorReduceContract` and `TensorExpand` differ are due, respectively, to the following equivalent results:

```
> Out = TensorContract[n~tp~m~tp~p,{{40,41},{43,45},{46,47},{48,49}}]
> Out = n~tp~TensorContract[m,{{4,5},{7,9},{10,11},{12,13}}]~tp~p
```