# Nested TensorContract bug

Tags: bugs, tensors

**Bug introduced in version 9.0.0 or 9.0.1 and fixed in 10.1 or 10.2**

---

When nesting `TensorContract` the result I get is wrong.

Input:

```
TensorContract[TensorContract[A, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}], {{1, 2}}]
```

Expected output:

```
TensorContract[A, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}}]
```

Actual output (Mac version 10.0.0):

```
During evaluation of In[1]:= TensorContract::lvreps: Contractions {{1,3},{2,4},{3,6}} contain repeated levels. >>
Out[1]= TensorContract[A, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}]
```

Declaring `A` as an array does not help. Am I missing something? Is there a workaround?

Related: [Error messages from TensorContract and TensorReduce](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61719/error-messages-from-tensorcontract-and-tensorreduce)

Comment: I can reproduce this on version 10.0.2 Linux x64. I agree it should be a bug.

Comment: I can also reproduce this on version 9.0.1.0, Linux x86 (64-bit).